# HTML Table : put an image or circle on border

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td  valign="top" align="center" style=" padding-left: 30px; padding: 10px; border-left: thin gray solid; ">
      <p style="padding-left: 50px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600;"> 
        <span style="color: #ee163a; font-size: 12px;">08:30 am - 09:30 am</span><br>
        <span style="color: black; font-size: 10px;">Tea, Registration and Networking </span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

I want to put an image or circle on the starting of `left border`.

Just like in the image.

[image: Here is the image]

PS: Cant' use `div` , have to stick to `table` and **inline css** , only.

(I am making an HTML emailer)

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried `border-image`. but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't support `position` property. so it will not work in outlook. if you have static content then you may create the same type of image and put it in you code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td  valign="top" align="center" style=" padding-left: 30px; padding: 10px; border-left: thin gray solid;">
      <p style="width:15px; height:15px; margin-left:-18px; margin-top:10px; background:red; border-radius:15px; float:left; "></p>

      <p style="padding-left: 50px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600;"> 
        <span style="color: #ee163a; font-size: 12px;">08:30 am - 09:30 am</span><br>
        <span style="color: black; font-size: 10px;">Tea, Registration and Networking </span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

Comment: cant' use `position` property. as I am making HTML emailer. have to stick to `table` and **inline css** only.

Comment: You can do it with inline css too

Comment: yes.. but i can't use `position` property. as some email clients don't render `position` property.

Comment: in that case you can use margin in negative  also

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but you have to try with email client:
https://jsfiddle.net/L6sc9smp/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td  valign="top" align="center" style=" padding-left: 30px; padding: 10px; border-left: thin gray solid; ">
    <div style="width:15px; height:15px; background: red; border-radius:100%; margin-left:-10px">

    </div>
      <p style="padding-left: 50px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600;"> 
        <span style="color: #ee163a; font-size: 12px;">08:30 am - 09:30 am</span><br>
        <span style="color: black; font-size: 10px;">Tea, Registration and Networking </span>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

If this don't work instead of using border on table use border on div inside td o something similar.

Comment: thank you.. but it didn't work in email client. the circle moved from its desired place